# GlassFish server: Remote server does not listen for requests

Tags: java, glassfish, java-server

After installing and successfully create domain1, I tried some services on. However after updating my windows on the next day. the server can't start on either Eclipse nor terminal. There is a directory for domain1 at "glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1".

On terminal I got this error:
$ ./asadmin start-domain domain1

> Can't find the default domains directory.  There is no value for this
>   system property: com.sun.aas.domainsRoot Command start-domain failed.

On Eclipse, I got this runtime exception:
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\glassfish4\glassfish\config\osgi.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.MainHelper.mergePlatformConfiguration(MainHelper.java:571)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.MainHelper.buildStartupContext(MainHelper.java:391)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:80)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\glassfish4\glassfish\config\osgi.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.MainHelper$PlatformHelper.readPlatformConfiguration(MainHelper.java:700)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.MainHelper$FelixHelper.readPlatformConfiguration(MainHelper.java:759)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.MainHelper.mergePlatformConfiguration(MainHelper.java:569)
    ... 3 more
```

Versions I used:
java version "1.7.0_79"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

GlassFish 4

Please, any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Reinstall glassfish.

Comment: Do not reinstall GlassFish. There is no reason to do that and it won't help.

Answer (score 2):

#### The answer to your question is that you need to run `asadmin start-domain`.

---

The error message is telling you the problem. You are calling the command `start-admin`, but that is not a valid command. It also tells you that the closest command is `start-domain` which is the command you should be using.

The cause of the error message is that `asadmin` supports both local and remote commands. Local commands can be run while the server is offline because they are all run on the same machine where they are called. Remote commands need to have a running server, because they connect to the Domain Admin Server (DAS) on port 4848.

In your case, the `start-admin` command doesn't exist, so GlassFish tried and failed to find a matching local command. When it tried to find a matching remote command, it failed because no GlassFish server was running.

Comment: even when i use the start-domain can't start!
BTW how to turn on the machine server? since technical stuff turn off some services on my machine and set them to be manually turned on. but I don't know which one to turning on.

Comment: What's the new error you get when you try `asadmin start-domain`?

Comment: Can't find the default domains directory. There is no value for this system property: com.sun.aas.domainsRoot
Command start-domain failed.

Comment: if I tried creat domain:
$ ./asadmin create-domain domain2
CLI138: Invalid domain path, null

Comment: The default domains directory is `glassfish4/glassfish/domains`. Check that directory exists (even if it is empty) and that you have the right permissions to modify it. These two failures would be down to a directory that either doesn't exist or that GlassFish can't modify.

Comment: I have the domain1 directory: C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1

Comment: This is really a different question to the one I answered. The comments section wasn't built for this, it would be best to ask a new question. I find it interesting that your domain directory is a Windows path, but the create domain command you posted looks to be a Linux command prompt.